# Problem getting an integer from SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am working on an iPhone project where we need to fetch data from aa sqlite database. I have done this many times before, and everything works out fine. But now I am having problems fetching the value of an integer field (the primary key).

The varchar fields I can fetch with:

```
NSString *forfatter=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 11)];
```

I suppose i have to use sqlite3_column_int for this, but i cant find out how to get the number right. When i NSLog it, it always comes out wrong, like: "107096896" instead of "35".

Here is one of the ways i tried to do it:

```
int pKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
NSLog(@"fant id: %i",pKey);
```

I also tried with NSIntegers and NSUIntegers. Can anyone help me out with this one? I would be very grateful!

Comment: Is the query itself returning what you think it is? (If it isn't, you've got to fix that first.)

Comment: You are right, Donald. It wasnt what i thought... Put your comment as an answer and ill check it as answered...

Answer (score 0):

As Donald points out above, something was wrong with the stored data. It traces back to my insert statements where i used this code to insert the int:

```
int newID=8;
sqlite3_bind_int(insertStmt,  1, newID);
```

If i use NSInteger instead, it works out:

```
NSInteger newID=8;
sqlite3_bind_int(insertStmt,  1, newID);
```

Comment: Frankly, that would worry me.  sqlite3_bind_int() is documented to take an int as its third parameter, so there is something weird going on.